# Azure devops release variables are not getting resolved in custom server task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Below Release Variables are not getting resolved at run time when tried in a custom server task on a Release Pipeline.

- System.JobName
- System.JobDisplayName
- System.StageDisplayName
- System.DefinitionName

I am able to fetch JobId by using $(system.JobId), but not other job details (JobName) as mentioned above.
Am I missing anything here:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohan, where do you get that pic? I mean how do you configure the task? I tested it in simple cmd task in classic release pipeline and those values were successfully expanded.

Comment: The image is a screenshot from azure release pipelines console log. This issue is very specific when tried with a custom task in server job of a release pipeline.

Answer (score -2):

Those YAML pipeline variables. They will not work in a classic release pipeline.

Use the release-specific equivalents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables

Comment: Would these variables still be accessiblefor an agentless job in the Release pipeline?

Comment: Hi Daniel, all these variables are getting resolved in agent jobs. This issue is very specific when tried with a custom task in server job of a release pipeline. One more thing I observed is, we are able to resolve System.JobId, but not other job details like System.JobdisplayName. I see we can use variables other than RM variables in release pipelines. But only above mentioned few are not getting resolved.